# How to generate language fragment bundles to localize Carbon products

Tags: ant, wso2

In the blog [*How to generate language fragment bundles to localize Carbon products*](http://tanyamadurapperuma.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/localizing-wso2-carbon-products-part-2.html) by Tanya Madurapperuma, I am having the following problem. Once generated the language bundles with `ant localize` command, these bundles are generated in the `CARBON_HOME/repository/components/dropins/` folder. The problem is that when I run the tool I'm not looking to change the language to Spanish. I would appreciate help to correct what I may be missing to do?

Note: All resources.properties files are translated into Spanish.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the jars with translated resources.properties files in you dropins folder, you need to restart the server and set the Locale setting of your browser to Spanish.

Locale should be changed in the browser, and then the server will pick the matching resources files to use.

**UPDATE:**

There are some problems here.
First, there's a bug if you have multiple directories in /resources directory. For now, you can make sure that you have only one directory inside resources directory when you run localize task.

You should have the properties files inside a directory with the bundle name, without the tree structure. So your resources directory should look like this.

```
../resources/
└── org.wso2.carbon.i18n_4.2.0
    ├── JSResources_es.properties
    └── Resources_es.properties
```

You need to include the locale code as `_es` in your files as shown above.

Also the localize tool seems to append `i18n` at the end of the folder structure of the built jar. This works with ui bundles but in the case of org.wso2.carbon.i18n it looks as `org/wso2/carbon/i18n/i18n`. So open the built jar in dropins folder and remove the extra i18n folder so that the jar tree structure looks like following.

```
../repository/components/dropins/org.wso2.carbon.i18n.languageBundle_4.2.0.jar
├── META-INF
│   └── MANIFEST.MF
└── org
    └── wso2
        └── carbon
            └── i18n
                ├── JSResources_es.properties
                └── Resources_es.properties
```

Comment: Grateful for your reply.

I develop the test with the explained in your response, but continues the tool without charge me the Spanish translation.

If you are interested I can send the generated jar so you can see if the problem is the internal structure that has the package itself.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Did you get this to work?

The place I doubt that you might have gone wrong is the folder structure in the resources folder. (You can place your resource files anywhere and execute command as **ant localize -Dresources.directory=path_to_your_resources_directory**)

Also note that a resource folder should have the proper naming conventions of the osgi bundle. 
Ex: org.wso2.carbon.claim.mgt.ui_4.2.0 (This entire thing is name of the folder)

If you still couldn't get this to work mail me your resources folder to tanyamadurapperuma@gmail.com

Comment: Send me the resources folder not the generated jars.Also mention which product and its version that you are going to localize. (Ex: like WSO2 ESB 4.6.0)